# Is there a way to Load any image to screen and edit it graphically in winapi C++ (Image Editor)?

Tags: c++, image, winapi, graphics, image-editor

I am trying to make an Image Editor in C++ (winapi). I've only done setting up the window and menus like File (consisting New, Open, Save, Exit). But I am completely clueless about how to load the image requested by the client, and how to let them draw over it and save it.

I don't think, the initial code matters here, That's why I'm not posting it. Let me know if you need it.

Comment: Too broad a question for Stack Overflow, which is meant for specific programming problems and not general "how do I write a program" type questions. There are several open source image editors around (e.g. Paint.NET), maybe have a look at how they do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using C++ and winapi then you should consider using the MFC framework. This provides pretty good wrappers for all the native windows graphics objects and actions; and, what I find especially useful is the "CImage" class. This has a "Load" member that, given a path to a file, can open an image in any of the 'standard' graphics formats (bitmap, GIF, JPEG and TIFF). Once open, you can use the class's functions like "BitBlt" to render the object's image to a View (window). You can also extract a 'handle' to the underlying BITMAP object (the actual array of pixel colours), and with that you can apply any changes the user makes to the displayed image.

I use this class extensively in one of my software projects, which has a large set of image-editing/-processing operations.

Sorry if this is a bit vague - but, then again, so is your question!

Comment: Is it possible in raw winapi? Do I really need to use MFC framework? I'm asking because I've never used MFC.

Comment: Yes it is possible using raw WinAPI. But you probably need more knowledge and experience than you have right now. You need to work through Petzold's book.

Comment: I don't know of any raw winapi function(s) that allow you to read in data from files in formats like GIF, JPEG or TIFF. Even loading a Windows BITMAP file can be tedious. But, for sure, there will be libraries available 'out there'. But, if you have Visual Studio, creating a basic MFC application is really easy - it will generate the source code for a 'dummy' MDI (multiple document interface) application, with all the standard menus, etc.; all you have to do is add the actual worker code.